# iOS Objective-C wrapper for Google Docs

Tags: objective-c, ios, wrapper, google-docs-api

Has anyone integrated google docs into their iOS app?  Having gone through the example code, the API for Google Docs is far more complicated than I would have expected, and the examples are all MacOS.  Yes there is iOS support, but there is a distinct lack of example code on how to use it, and the documentation is somewhat lacking.

I did find an interface class on the web, but it was based on an older, deprecated version of the Google Docs API, and it doesn't compile with XCode 4.2.

What I'm after is a relatively straight forward interface that allows:

1. Logging in/out from a google docs account.
2. Getting a list of documents within that account (optionally of a specific type), possibly with the ability to navigate a folder structure.
3. Being able to download a specific document to local storage.
4. Being able to upload a specific document to google docs.

I've started writing such an interface, but so far it's way more involved than I had allowed for.  If anyone has any suggestions, or samples that they can direct me to, I'd really appreciate it.

My preference is for the wrapper to be OS neutral; meaning I want to be able to use the same interface in both MacOS and iOS.  Again, this is what I've started writing, but I can't help feeling that I must be reinventing the wheel here.

Thanks

Comment: +1, google has terrible source code.

Comment: And yet it apparently follows the style guide...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so in the absence of any answers from others, I bit the bullet and wrote a wrapper myself.

I now have  single wrapper that works for both Mac OS and iOS that dramatically simplifies the interface with Google Docs.

Below is all of the code for the actual interface.  I should point out that this class acts as a singleton, and you need to customise it slightly for each project by updating the lines:

```
#define GOOGLE_DATA_CLIENT_ID @"<client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_SECRET @"<google data secret>"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_USERNAME @"googleDocsUsername"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_PASSWORD @"googleDocsPassword"
```

with the appropriate values you get from Google.

I also point out that the class stores passwords via NSUserDefaults, and uses a separate utility class to do this in an encrypted fashion.  Rather than clog this answer here with all of that extra code, I've created a repository in bitbucket at:

https://bitbucket.org/pkclsoft/gdatainterface

which contains an entire XCode project that builds two targets, one for Mac OS and one for iOS.  Ive used those both in an app that is in the app store now with great results.  It may be that whilst this project builds for me you have to tweak it for your purposes.  The project contains a complete set of the Google SDK that builds and runs with my code.  I included it to try and reduce the risk of incompatibilities with newer versions of the SDK for anyone grabbing it.

Here is the interface spec as it currently stands:

```
//
//  GDataInterface.h
//  GDataInterface
//
//  Some of the code in this class is from the original GData sample code, but it has been
//  enhanced somewhat and made to work on both iOS and MacOS transparently.
//
//  Created by Peter Easdown on 19/12/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 PKCLsoft. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import "GDataDocs.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#import "GData/GData.h"
#endif

@interface GDataInterfaceTypes

// This handler is used by methods that have no explicit result.  The boolean value indicates
// the success or failure of the the methods action.
//
typedef void (^CompletionHandler)(BOOL successful);

// This handler is called to update a progress indicator as a file is uploaded.
//
typedef void (^UploadProgressHandler)(double min, double max, double value);

// This handler is called to update a progress indicator as a file is downloaded.
//
typedef void (^DownloadProgressHandler)(double min, double max, double value);

@end

@interface GDataInterface : NSObject {

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    // Needed so that when authenticating under iOS, we can push the google authentication
    // view, and later pop it.
    //
    UIViewController *rootController_;
#endif

    GDataFeedDocList *mDocListFeed;
    GDataServiceTicket *mDocListFetchTicket;
    NSError *mDocListFetchError;

    GDataFeedDocRevision *mRevisionFeed;
    GDataServiceTicket *mRevisionFetchTicket;
    NSError *mRevisionFetchError;

    GDataEntryDocListMetadata *mMetadataEntry;

    GDataServiceTicket *mUploadTicket;

    id uploadWindow;
    CompletionHandler uploadCompletionHandler;

    NSString *username_;
    NSString *password_;

}

// This handler is used when a list of documents has been requested.  The results parameter
// will be nil if the request failed.  If successful, then it will contain an array of 
// GDataEntryDocBase objects.
//
typedef void (^RetrievalCompletionHandler)(GDataFeedDocList* results, BOOL successful);

// This handler is used when a document has been downloaded.  If something prevented the 
// download from succeeding, then error parameter will be non-nil.
//
typedef void (^DocumentDownloadCompletionHandler)(NSData* fileContents, BOOL successful);

// Initializer that provides the username and password.
//
- (id) initWithUsername:(NSString*)username andPassword:(NSString*)password;

// Returns the shared instance of the class.  There will only ever be a single instance
// of this class.
//
+ (GDataInterface*) sharedInstance;

// Returns YES if currently signed in.
//
- (BOOL) isSignedIn;

// Signs in or out depending on current state, and executes the options completion handler
// block.  The window parameter is used to specify the root viewController object used when
// displaying login windows via GData, or error dialogs.
//
- (void) signInOrOutWithCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler forWindow:(id)window;

// Will retrieve a list of documents using the cached connection, and call the specified
// handler block, providing the list of documents, and a success/fail indication.
//
- (void) retrieveDocumentListWithCompletionHandler:(RetrievalCompletionHandler)handler;

// Will download the file at the specified URL.  This is not Google Docs specific and will work
// for any URL.  Be careful not to try and retrieve large files and the result is stored
// in memory.
//
- (void) downloadURL:(NSURL*)url withProgressHandler:(DownloadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(DocumentDownloadCompletionHandler)handler;

// Will download the specified google docs document.
//
- (void) downloadDocument:(GDataEntryDocBase*)document withProgressHandler:(DownloadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(DocumentDownloadCompletionHandler)handler;

// Uploads the document entry, optionally updating it with a new revision.
//
- (void) uploadEntry:(GDataEntryDocBase*)docEntry asNewRevision:(BOOL)newRevision forWindow:(id)window withProgressHandler:(UploadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler;

// Uploads the specified file to the authenticated google docs account.
//
- (void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path forWindow:(id)window withProgressHandler:(UploadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler;

// More for internal use than anything else.  Used to determine the mime type based on the google docs class
// and/or file extension.
//
- (void)getMIMEType:(NSString **)mimeType andEntryClass:(Class *)class forExtension:(NSString *)extension;

// Getter and Setter for username,
//
- (void) setUsername:(NSString*)newUsername;
- (NSString*) username;

// Getter and Setter for password.  The password will be encrypted before storing it in user preferances.
//
- (void) setPassword:(NSString*)newPassword;
- (NSString*) password;

// Returns the username that google is given for signing in.
//
- (NSString *)signedInUsername;

// Returns a static instance of the docs service.
//
+ (GDataServiceGoogleDocs *)docsService;

@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
//
//  GDataInterface.m
//  GDataInterface
//
//  Created by Peter Easdown on 19/12/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 PKCLsoft. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GDataInterface.h"
#import "Util.h"
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "GData.h"
#else
#import "GData/GTMOAuth2WindowController.h"
//#import "GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet.h"
#endif

#define GOOGLE_DATA_CLIENT_ID @"<client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_SECRET @"<google data secret>"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_USERNAME @"googleDocsUsername"
#define GOOGLE_DATA_PASSWORD @"googleDocsPassword"

@interface GDataInterface (PrivateMethods)

- (GDataServiceTicket *) uploadTicket;
- (void) setUploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket;

- (GDataFeedDocList *)docListFeed;
- (void)setDocListFeed:(GDataFeedDocList *)feed;
- (NSError *)docListFetchError;
- (void)setDocListFetchError:(NSError *)error;
- (GDataServiceTicket *)docListFetchTicket;
- (void)setDocListFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket;

@end

@implementation GDataInterface

static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"GDataInterface: Google Docs";

// Initializer that provides the username and password.
//
- (id) initWithUsername:(NSString*)username andPassword:(NSString*)password {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        username_ = [username retain];
        password_ = [password retain];
        [[GDataInterface docsService] setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username_ password:password_];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setUsername:(NSString*)newUsername {
    username_ = [newUsername retain];
    [[GDataInterface docsService] setUserCredentialsWithUsername:newUsername password:password_];
}

- (NSString*) username {
    return username_;
}

- (void) setPassword:(NSString*)newPassword {
    password_ = [newPassword retain];
    [[GDataInterface docsService] setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username_ password:newPassword];
    [Util setPassword:newPassword forKey:GOOGLE_DATA_PASSWORD];
}

- (NSString*) password {
    return password_;
}


static GDataInterface *shared_instance_;

// Returns the shared instance of the class.  There will only ever be a single instance
// of this class.
//
+ (GDataInterface*) sharedInstance {
    if (shared_instance_ == nil) {
        shared_instance_ = [[GDataInterface alloc] initWithUsername:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:GOOGLE_DATA_USERNAME] andPassword:[Util getPassword:GOOGLE_DATA_PASSWORD]];

        // Load the OAuth token from the keychain, if it was previously saved
        NSString *clientID = GOOGLE_DATA_CLIENT_ID;
        NSString *clientSecret = GOOGLE_DATA_SECRET;

        GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName clientID:clientID clientSecret:clientSecret];
#else
        auth = [GTMOAuth2WindowController authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                  clientID:clientID
                                                              clientSecret:clientSecret];
#endif

        [[GDataInterface docsService] setAuthorizer:auth];
    }

    return shared_instance_;
}

- (NSString *)signedInUsername {
    // Get the email address of the signed-in user
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [[GDataInterface docsService] authorizer];
    BOOL isSignedIn = auth.canAuthorize;

    if (isSignedIn) {
        return auth.userEmail;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL) isSignedIn {
    return ([self signedInUsername] != nil);
}

- (void)runSigninThenInvokeHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler forWindow:(id)window {
    // Applications should have client ID and client secret strings
    // hardcoded into the source, but the sample application asks the
    // developer for the strings
    NSString *clientID = GOOGLE_DATA_CLIENT_ID;
    NSString *clientSecret = GOOGLE_DATA_SECRET;

    // Show the OAuth 2 sign-in controller
    NSString *scope = [GTMOAuth2Authentication scopeWithStrings:
                       [GDataServiceGoogleDocs authorizationScope],
                       [GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet authorizationScope],
                       nil];

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    NSAssert((window != nil), @"window must be a non-nil navigation controller");

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch 
                      controllerWithScope:scope
                      clientID:clientID 
                      clientSecret:clientSecret 
                      keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                      completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {

                          [rootController_ dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                          [rootController_ release];
                          rootController_ = nil;

                          // callback
                          if (error == nil) {
                              [[GDataInterface docsService] setAuthorizer:auth];

                              username_ = [self signedInUsername];

                              handler(YES);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error);
                              NSData *responseData = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"]; // kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDataKey
                              if ([responseData length] > 0) {
                                  // show the body of the server's authentication failure response
                                  NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                                  NSLog(@"%@", str);
                              }
                              handler(NO);
                          }
                      }];

    // Optional: display some html briefly before the sign-in page loads
    NSString *html = @"<html><body bgcolor=silver><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
    viewController.initialHTMLString = html;

    // For iOS, window is a navigation controller.
    //
    rootController_ = [(UIViewController*)window retain];
    [rootController_ presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

#else
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[GTMOAuth2WindowController class]];
    GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController;
    windowController = [GTMOAuth2WindowController controllerWithScope:scope
                                                             clientID:clientID
                                                         clientSecret:clientSecret
                                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                       resourceBundle:frameworkBundle];

    [windowController signInSheetModalForWindow:window
                              completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {
                                  // callback
                                  if (error == nil) {
                                      [[GDataInterface docsService] setAuthorizer:auth];
                                      username_ = [auth userEmail];
                                      handler(YES);
                                  } else {
                                      handler(NO);
                                  }
                              }];
#endif
}

- (void) signInOrOutWithCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler forWindow:(id)window {
    if (![self isSignedIn]) {
        // Sign in
        [self runSigninThenInvokeHandler:handler forWindow:window];
    } else {
        // Sign out
        GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [GDataInterface docsService];

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];
#else
        [GTMOAuth2WindowController removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];
#endif

        [service setAuthorizer:nil];
        handler(YES);
    }
}

- (void) retrieveDocumentListWithCompletionHandler:(RetrievalCompletionHandler)handler {

    [self setDocListFeed:nil];
    [self setDocListFetchError:nil];
    [self setDocListFetchTicket:nil];

    GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [GDataInterface docsService];
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;

    // Fetching a feed gives us 25 responses by default.  We need to use
    // the feed's "next" link to get any more responses.  If we want more than 25
    // at a time, instead of calling fetchDocsFeedWithURL, we can create a
    // GDataQueryDocs object, as shown here.

    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs docsFeedURL];

    GDataQueryDocs *query = [GDataQueryDocs documentQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    [query setMaxResults:1000];
    [query setShouldShowFolders:NO];

    ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                       completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {
                           // callback
                           [self setDocListFeed:(GDataFeedDocList *)feed];
                           [self setDocListFetchError:error];
                           [self setDocListFetchTicket:nil];

                           if (handler != nil) {
                               handler((GDataFeedDocList *)feed, (error == nil));
                           }
                       }];

    [self setDocListFetchTicket:ticket];
}

- (void) downloadDocument:(GDataEntryDocBase*)document withProgressHandler:(DownloadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(DocumentDownloadCompletionHandler)handler {

    // the content src attribute is used for downloading
    NSURL *exportURL = [[document content] sourceURL];

    if (exportURL != nil) {
        GDataQuery *query = [GDataQuery queryWithFeedURL:exportURL];
        [query addCustomParameterWithName:@"exportFormat"
                                    value:@"txt"];
        NSURL *downloadURL = [query URL];
        // Read the document's contents asynchronously from the network

        // requestForURL:ETag:httpMethod: sets the user agent header of the
        // request and, when using ClientLogin, adds the authorization header
        NSURLRequest *request = [[GDataInterface docsService] requestForURL:downloadURL
                                                                       ETag:nil
                                                                 httpMethod:nil];

        GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [fetcher setAuthorizer:[[GDataInterface docsService] authorizer]];

        __block double maxSize = 10240.0;

        if (progressHandler != nil) {            
            [fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar) {
                if ([[fetcher response] expectedContentLength] > 0) {
                    maxSize = [[fetcher response] expectedContentLength];
                } else if ([dataReceivedSoFar length] > maxSize) {
                    maxSize += 5120.0;
                }

                progressHandler(0.0, maxSize, (double)[dataReceivedSoFar length]);
            }];
        }

        [fetcher setCommentWithFormat:@"downloading \"%@\"", [[document title] stringValue]];
        [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (progressHandler != nil) {
                // Update the progress handler with a "complete" progress.
                //
                progressHandler(0.0, (double)[data length], (double)[data length]);
            }

            // callback
            if (error == nil) {
                // Successfully downloaded the document
                //                
                if (handler != nil) {
                    handler(data, YES);
                }
            } else {
                if (handler != nil) {
                    handler(nil, NO);
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void) downloadURL:(NSURL*)url withProgressHandler:(DownloadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(DocumentDownloadCompletionHandler)handler {

    NSURL *downloadURL = [url copy];
    // Read the document's contents asynchronously from the network

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];

    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];

    __block double maxSize = 10240.0;

    if (progressHandler != nil) {            
        [fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar) {
            if ([[fetcher response] expectedContentLength] > 0) {
                maxSize = [[fetcher response] expectedContentLength];
            } else if ([dataReceivedSoFar length] > maxSize) {
                maxSize += 5120.0;
            }

            progressHandler(0.0, maxSize, (double)[dataReceivedSoFar length]);
        }];
    }

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (progressHandler != nil) {
            progressHandler(0.0, (double)[data length], (double)[data length]);
        }

        // callback
        if (error == nil) {
            // Successfully downloaded the document
            //                
            if (handler != nil) {
                handler(data, YES);
            }
        } else {
            if (handler != nil) {
                handler(nil, NO);
            }
        }
    }];

    // Block, waiting for 60 seconds for the download.
    //
    [fetcher waitForCompletionWithTimeout:60.0];

    if ([fetcher isFetching] == YES) {
        // OK, so this looks like we've timed out waiting for the download to complete.  Cancel the 
        // fetch.
        //
        [fetcher stopFetching];

        if (handler != nil) {
            handler(nil, NO);
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark Upload

- (void)getMIMEType:(NSString **)mimeType andEntryClass:(Class *)class forExtension:(NSString *)extension {

    // Mac OS X's UTI database doesn't know MIME types for .doc and .xls
    // so GDataEntryBase's MIMETypeForFileAtPath method isn't helpful here

    struct MapEntry {
        NSString *extension;
        NSString *mimeType;
        NSString *className;
    };

    static struct MapEntry sMap[] = {
        { @"csv", @"text/csv", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"doc", @"application/msword", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"docx", @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"ods", @"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet", @"GDataEntrySpreadsheetDoc" },
        { @"odt", @"application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"pps", @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", @"GDataEntryPresentationDoc" },
        { @"ppt", @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", @"GDataEntryPresentationDoc" },
        { @"rtf", @"application/rtf", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"sxw", @"application/vnd.sun.xml.writer", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"txt", @"text/plain", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"xls", @"application/vnd.ms-excel", @"GDataEntrySpreadsheetDoc" },
        { @"xlsx", @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @"GDataEntrySpreadsheetDoc" },
        { @"jpg", @"image/jpeg", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"jpeg", @"image/jpeg", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"png", @"image/png", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"bmp", @"image/bmp", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"gif", @"image/gif", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"html", @"text/html", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"htm", @"text/html", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"tsv", @"text/tab-separated-values", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"tab", @"text/tab-separated-values", @"GDataEntryStandardDoc" },
        { @"pdf", @"application/pdf", @"GDataEntryPDFDoc" },
        { nil, nil, nil }
    };

    NSString *lowerExtn = [extension lowercaseString];

    for (int idx = 0; sMap[idx].extension != nil; idx++) {
        if ([lowerExtn isEqual:sMap[idx].extension]) {
            *mimeType = sMap[idx].mimeType;
            *class = NSClassFromString(sMap[idx].className);
            return;
        }
    }

    *mimeType = nil;
    *class = nil;
    return;
}

- (void) uploadEntry:(GDataEntryDocBase*)docEntry asNewRevision:(BOOL)newRevision forWindow:(id)window withProgressHandler:(UploadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler {

    uploadWindow = [window retain];
    uploadCompletionHandler = [handler copy];

    NSURL *uploadURL;

    if (newRevision == YES) {
        GDataQueryDocs *query = [GDataQueryDocs queryWithFeedURL:[[docEntry 
                                                                   uploadEditLink] URL]]; 
        [query setShouldCreateNewRevision:YES]; 
        uploadURL = [query URL];
    } else {
        uploadURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs docsUploadURL];
    }

    // make service tickets call back into our upload progress selector
    GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [GDataInterface docsService];
    [service setServiceUploadProgressHandler:^(GDataServiceTicketBase *ticket, unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead, unsigned long long dataLength) {
        if (progressHandler != nil) {
            progressHandler(0.0, (double)dataLength, (double)numberOfBytesRead);
        }
    }];

    // insert the entry into the docList feed
    //
    // to update (replace) an existing entry by uploading a new file,
    // use the fetchEntryByUpdatingEntry:forEntryURL: with the URL from
    // the entry's uploadEditLink
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;

    if (newRevision == YES) {        
        ticket = [service fetchEntryByUpdatingEntry:docEntry 
                                        forEntryURL:uploadURL 
                                           delegate:self 
                                  didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFileTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
    } else {
        ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:docEntry
                                          forFeedURL:uploadURL
                                            delegate:self
                                   didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFileTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
    }

    [ticket setUploadProgressHandler:^(GDataServiceTicketBase *ticket, unsigned long long numberOfBytesRead, unsigned long long dataLength) {
        // progress callback
        if (progressHandler != nil) {
            progressHandler(0.0, (double)dataLength, (double)numberOfBytesRead);
        }
    }];

    // we turned automatic retry on when we allocated the service, but we
    // could also turn it on just for this ticket

    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];
    [service setServiceUploadProgressHandler:nil];
}

- (void)uploadFileAtPath:(NSString *)path forWindow:(id)window withProgressHandler:(UploadProgressHandler)progressHandler andCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)handler {

    NSString *errorMsg = nil;

    // make a new entry for the file

    NSString *mimeType = nil;
    Class entryClass = nil;

    NSString *extn = [path pathExtension];
    [self getMIMEType:&mimeType andEntryClass:&entryClass forExtension:extn];

    if (!mimeType) {
        // for other file types, see if we can get the type from the Mac OS
        // and use a generic file document entry class
        mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path
                                         defaultMIMEType:nil];
        entryClass = [GDataEntryFileDoc class];
    }

    if (mimeType && entryClass) {

        GDataEntryDocBase *newEntry = [entryClass documentEnt
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any reference or URL that I can get more information about implementation ? I also need such wrapper or SDK to Google Docs from iOS . Thx

Comment: I've got to retest the MacOS side of it, but apart from that it's working really well.  I'll look at polishing it a bit an putting it up on github.

Comment: I'd be **very** interested in this as well!

Comment: OK, I'll make some time this week to tidy it up a big and post it.  Sorry to all that have been waiting.

Comment: I've update my answer above with the full code of the class I wrote/built.  There's also a link to an XCode project.